# How do I access multiple objects from another method in the same class java?

Tags: java

Here's my code, I'm trying to access e1,e2,e3 in my getData() method but it's not working. How do I get my second method to recognize the first ones but keeping the methods separate?

```
public class Model {

    public Model() {
        loadData();
    }

    public void loadData() { 
        Employee e1 = new Employee("John Smith", "California, PA.", "Dr. Robertson junior.");

        Employee e2 = new Employee("Kyle Alston",  "State College, PA.", "SmithTown");

        Employee e3 = new Employee("Tommy Smith", "Baskeville, PA.", "Chicago");
        
      
    }
    public String getData(int n)  { 
        if(n == 1){
            return e1;

        }
        if(n == 2){
            return e2;

    }
        if(n == 3){
            return e3;

    }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

I tried Model data = new loadData().e1 but I don't think that works.

Thanks in advance. I'm not allowed to change the parameters.

Comment: You need to understand 'scope'. The variables e1,  e2, e3 simply **do not exist** when loadData is not being executed.  You should declare them as instance (member) variables.  Having said that, the code would be more succinct using an array.

Comment: @user16632363 so there's no way to access them?

Comment: You can't access something that **does not exist**,  The variables come into existence when loadData is entered, and cease to exist just prior to return from loadData.

Comment: @user16632363 does that mean my loadData() method is useless?

Comment: Your `loadData()` method creates employees that all get lost when the method finishes executing.

Comment: As currently written, yes.  Hang on, I'll write up an answer.  This is too confining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use member variables to retain values from one method to the next.

```
public class Model {

    private Employee e1, e2, e3;

    public Model() {
        loadData();
    }

    public void loadData() { 
        e1 = new Employee("John Smith", "California, PA.", "Dr. Robertson junior.");
        e2 = new Employee("Kyle Alston",  "State College, PA.", "SmithTown");
        e3 = new Employee("Tommy Smith", "Baskeville, PA.", "Chicago");    
    }

    public String getData(int n)  { 
        if (n == 1) {
            return e1;
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return e2;
        }
        if (n == 3) {
            return e3;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

For comparison, rewritten using a simple array.  The benefit here is that getData is now independent of the number of employees.

```
public class Model {

    private Employee[] e;

    public Model() {
        loadData();
    }

    public void loadData() { 
        e = new Employee[3];
        e[0] = new Employee("John Smith", "California, PA.", "Dr. Robertson junior.");
        e[1] = new Employee("Kyle Alston",  "State College, PA.", "SmithTown");
        e[2] = new Employee("Tommy Smith", "Baskeville, PA.", "Chicago");    
    }

    public String getData(int n)  { 
        if (n <= 0 || n > e.length) {
           return null;
        }
        return e[n-1];
    }
}
```

I might consider using an ArrayList rather than an array, but the array is more fundamental in Java, which I think makes it a better choice for initial learning.